# Can Application Receive Call Using Modem Services

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, voip, modem

I'm working on a project based on IVR(Interactive Voice Response). In which  registration, modification in DB will take place by dialing a telephone number and following simple steps, like that which is used in telecom help centers to change our tariff or SMS packages etc.

Can I use simple voice modem with C# code with TAPI as back-end to mange all this?
Actually, I have "conexant hda d330 mdc v.92 modem". Can I use this to make this type of application...?

If yes, can we handle more than one call on this modem?

If not, what hardware will be required to perform this?

Comment: If you manage to make TAPI work, please show some samples. I struggled by weeks with that and finally decided to handle the modem myself via System.IO using COM ports

Comment: @HighCore, 
I'm new to TAPI, I don't know how to refer and use COM Ports within c#, can u plz gave me some sample code? how to talk with modem in c#?
-thanks in advance.